# Как найти координаты контура графа?

Tags: алгоритм

Есть определенный 2D граф точек с некой формой. Нужно получить координаты точек, которые образуют контур этой фигуры, то есть границы фигуры, без внутренних нодов. Какой алгоритм для этого лучше подойдет?

Comment: мб джарвиса? правда он даст выпуклую оболочку

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Взять нижнюю точку (самую левую, если имеется несколько точек с минимальной Y координатой). Она принадлежит внешнему контуру.

Найти смежный с ней узел под минимальным углом от оси OX, перейти к нему.

Далее каждый раз переходим к смежному узлу, выбранному  по минимальному углу поворота от предыдущего (как бы идём по левой стенке). Угол поворота можно вычислить через atan2 (приведя результат к диапазону 0..2*Pi)

Пример порядка обхода

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]